# How to disable some options and how to change the font colour of a <select> component using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu

I have my following table and the **ESTADO** field is a dropdown list that shows the possible statuses, what I want to do is that when the IN PROGRESS status is selected, the FINISHED status is disabled and only the ERROR status can be selected, and that they be seen by colors, to say if the FINISHED state is selected it is painted in black color, the IN PROGRESS state is painted in blue color and the ERROR state in red color

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="guardar()">Guardar</button>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">ESTADO</th>
            <th scope="col">COMENTARIO</th>
            <th scope="col">HORA INICIO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let contr of control">
            <td>{{contr.id}}</td>
            <td>
                <select class="select" (change)="onChangeList($event, contr)">
                    <option value="0">{{contr.cveEstado}}</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado" [disabled]="estatus.cveEstado== 'INP'? 'disabled': null">
                        {{estatus.descripcionEstado}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>{{contr.comentario}</td>
            <td>{{contr.horaInicio}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my component.ts, the method **obtenerListaControl()** is to list what is in the **CONTROL** table, the method **obtenerListaEstado()** is to list the description of the states of the **ESTADO** table, since in the CONTROL table it only brings the the state key and not the description

The **onChangeList(e,contr)** method to retrieve what is selected in the dropdown list

```
     control: Control[] = [];
    controlModel: Control =  new Control();
    estadoModel: Estatus[] = [];
    idEst: number;
    isDisabled : boolean : false;

constructor(private controlService: ControlService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerListaControl();
    this.obtenerListaEstado();
}
    


    private obtenerListaControl(){
    this.controlService.obtenerControl().subscribe(response => {
      this.control = response.data;
    });
   }

   private obtenerListaEstado(){
    this.controlService.obtenerEstatus().subscribe(resp => {
      this.estadoModel = resp.data;
    });
   }
   
   onChangeList(e,contr){
    this.idEst = e.target.value;
    console.log("Option select:::::" +this.idEst);
   if(this.idEst == "INP"){
    this.isDisabled = false;
    }
  }

   guardar(){
    this.controlModel.cveEstado= this.idEst;
    this.controlService.updateEstado(this.controlModel).subscribe(data=>{
      this.controlModel=data;
    })
   }
```

what I don't know is how to disable the  options and that they can be displayed in different colors, COULD ANYONE HELP ME PLEASE?

THESE ARE THE STATUS THAT THE LIST SHOWS, SHOW THE DESCRIPTION

INP --- > IN PROGRESS

FIN ----> FINISHED

ERR ----> ERROR

**UPDATE**:
Add the modify **[disabled]="estatus.cveEstado== 'INP'? 'disabled': null"**  but the only thing it does is validate that if the status it brings is INP it disables it, but I want to add the condition, if it is equal to the ERR status, it disables the FIN status and the other enabled statuses

Answer (score 0):

To disable an option, it's pretty simple, you just need to add `[disabled]="...."` to the options:

```
<option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado" [disabled]="estatus.isDisabled">
   {{estatus.descripcionEstado}}
</option>
```

About the color, you can imagine something like:

```
<option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado" [style.color]="getOptionColor(estatus)">
   {{estatus.descripcionEstado}}
</option>
```

Where you need to define the function `getOptionColor(estatus)` that returns the desired color regarding the option

Comment: isDisabled should be an method in component.ts?

Comment: I dont know how to implememnt isDisabled, help please

Comment: I update the question to what I modified

Comment: I don't know what is your condition to disable or not. This is why I have written `isDisabled`

Comment: @Root93 Please check for example this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-disable-select-option?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I updated the question, I modify property [disabled],  
What I want to do is disable some options of the option depending on the status it has, for example if the status it brings is equal to INP (In porgress) disable the FIN status (FINISHED) and it will only allow me to select the ERR status,